# Weird CSS menu problem

Tags: php, html, css

I have this strange problem I need some help with.

This menu code goes to all the links and the stylesheet is style.css:

```
<div id="slider">
<table width="1282" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="336"></td>
    <td width="96"><a href="?p=for-publishers" <?php echo ($_GET['p']=='for-publishers') ? 'style="color:#98b755"' : ''  ?>>Publishers intro</a></td>
    <td width="91"><a href="?p=for-publishers/keyfeatures" <?php echo ($_GET['p']=='for-publishers/keyfeatures') ? 'style="color:#98b755"' : ''  ?>>Key features</a></td>
    <td width="125"><a href="?p=for-publishers/private-ad-exchange" <?php echo ($_GET['p']=='for-publishers/private-ad-exchange') ? 'style="color:#98b755"' : ''  ?>>Private Ad exchange</a></td>
    <td width="147"><a href="?p=for-publishers/optimize-demand-partners" <?php echo ($_GET['p']=='for-publishers/optimize-demand-partners') ? 'style="color:#98b755"' : ''  ?>>Optimize  Demand Partners</a></td>
    <td width="48"><a href="?p=for-publishers/display-textads-mobile" <?php echo ($_GET['p']=='for-publishers/display-textads-mobile') ? 'style="color:#98b755"' : ''  ?>>RTB</a></td>
    <td width="34"> <a href="?p=for-publishers/faq" <?php echo ($_GET['p']=='for-publishers/faq') ? 'style="color:#98b755"' : ''  ?>>FAQ</a></td>
    <td width="371"><a href="?p=get-started" <?php echo ($_GET['p']=='get-started') ? 'style="color:#98b755"' : ''  ?>>Get Started</a></td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

There should be no difference, but somehow the link on "for-publishers" theres an extra space.

You can see the problem on http://---www---seorapport---se

What could this be?

Just ask if you need further information. Thank you very much.

Comment: SO marks links with `rel=nofollow` so there's no reason to replace them with plain text.

Comment: You really shouldn't use <table> for menu and in-line CSS.... it's 2011! I think...

Comment: it can be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: I'm checking it out in FF4, and I don't see the space of which you speak...

Comment: @Theifmaster I don't really understand what you mean. SO marks?

@daGrevis This is made by a friend of mine and I'm supposed to fix the space. I can't change the whole menu system now unfortunately :P Is there a better way you can recommend? Or can I just remove the table? :)

@OZ_ Thank you, I'll look into it.

@espais If you check out the other links in the same menu you'll notice the difference. I'm looking at it in FF4 and it's the same in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `<table>` and the way you're making that menu is to put it nicely: *not good*.

You can quickly remove the "extra space" by adding `overflow: hidden` to `#slider`.

That will prevent the excessive `width` of `1282` on the `table` from causing the "extra space".

---

Looking more closely, I see there are **other issues**.

- This is the problem I just provided a fix for:

  [image]
- Here's another gap, and the one I suspect you were talking about:

  [image]
- The same stylesheet is being imported **three times**:

  ```
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
  ..
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <div class="menu">
  ..
  --><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  ```
- A bunch of JavaScript files aren't being loaded:

  [image]
- The HTML has some [nasty validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seorapport.se%2F%3Fp%3Dfor-publishers&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) concerning the opening and closing of tags.

Comment: @Thirtydot can I do something about it?

I tried overflow: hidden but unfortunately I didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: See my updated answer for some further problems with the site. I'm looking at how to actually fix the gap now.

Comment: Well, I was doing but you're live editing the site. Let me know if/when you need more help and I'll take a look (or if you resolve the problem).

Comment: @thirtydot Thank you very much for your help! I'm done editing now, and I'll look into those javascripts that aren't being loaded! Thanks man!

Comment: Btw, which tool are you using for validating? I'm using Web Developer Tool in FF4 but this doesn't give the same info as you are getting. Thx

Comment: The list of files is from the Net panel of [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/). The validation errors are coming from the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks man I'll check that validator out right away. I still haven't found out why that space is such a pain in the ass. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You should still fix all those errors, but I've found the cause. In your HTML source code, the whitespace between `</div> .. <div id="slider">` is "funny"/broken/"not actually whitespace". If you remove that "whitespace" it will be fixed. To be sure, rewrite `</div><div id="slider">` in the relevant place.